How can I count the cells in a pivot table based on multiple criteria?
I have created a pivot table from data that stores two components, Date and Rooms. In the pivot table I have grouped all the rooms on their matching date. I know want to count the rooms that fall within a range for everyday inthe pivot table. The range I want the numbers to fall into is is like 1000 - 1999, 2000 - 2999, etc.
I have posted a screenshot of my Excel, with the specific ranges, and how I have setup the Pivot table so far. How do I count the criteria across the entire pivot table.
Excel Document
I have figured out how to use the Countifs to count these numbers for one grouped day, but I dont know how to do that across multiple dates in the pivot table.

It seems to me the only solution is to add a column into the data table:

B2 =INT(C2/1000)*1000


You can either use a proper COUNTIFS or you can add a column to the source data to establish in which class the given room falls in and use a pivot table. Paste this in a a new sheet:



Date
Room
Class


0001-1999
2000-2999
3000-3999
8000-8999
9000-9499
9500-9999




08/01/2024
9592
=IF(MATCH($B2,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B2,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B2,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)


1
2000
3000
8000
9000
9500


08/01/2024
9784
=IF(MATCH($B3,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B3,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B3,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)


1999
2999
3999
8999
9499
9999


08/01/2024
9719
=IF(MATCH($B4,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B4,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B4,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

08/01/2024
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,">="&F$2,$B:$B,"<="&F$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,">="&G$2,$B:$B,"<="&G$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,">="&H$2,$B:$B,"<="&H$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,">="&I$2,$B:$B,"<="&I$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,">="&J$2,$B:$B,"<="&J$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,">="&K$2,$B:$B,"<="&K$3)


08/01/2024
9754
=IF(MATCH($B5,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B5,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B5,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

=E4+1
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E5,$B:$B,">="&F$2,$B:$B,"<="&F$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E5,$B:$B,">="&G$2,$B:$B,"<="&G$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E5,$B:$B,">="&H$2,$B:$B,"<="&H$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E5,$B:$B,">="&I$2,$B:$B,"<="&I$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E5,$B:$B,">="&J$2,$B:$B,"<="&J$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E5,$B:$B,">="&K$2,$B:$B,"<="&K$3)


08/01/2024
9220
=IF(MATCH($B6,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B6,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B6,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

=E5+1
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E6,$B:$B,">="&F$2,$B:$B,"<="&F$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E6,$B:$B,">="&G$2,$B:$B,"<="&G$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E6,$B:$B,">="&H$2,$B:$B,"<="&H$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E6,$B:$B,">="&I$2,$B:$B,"<="&I$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E6,$B:$B,">="&J$2,$B:$B,"<="&J$3)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E6,$B:$B,">="&K$2,$B:$B,"<="&K$3)


08/01/2024
9455
=IF(MATCH($B7,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B7,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B7,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










08/01/2024
9412
=IF(MATCH($B8,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B8,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B8,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










08/01/2024
9118
=IF(MATCH($B9,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B9,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B9,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

Min
Max (reversed)
Class






08/01/2024
9185
=IF(MATCH($B10,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B10,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B10,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

1
9999
0001-1999






09/01/2024
9630
=IF(MATCH($B11,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B11,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B11,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

2000
9499
2000-2999






09/01/2024
9681
=IF(MATCH($B12,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B12,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B12,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

3000
8999
3000-3999






09/01/2024
9542
=IF(MATCH($B13,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B13,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B13,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

8000
3999
8000-8999






09/01/2024
9503
=IF(MATCH($B14,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B14,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B14,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

9000
2999
9000-9499






09/01/2024
9882
=IF(MATCH($B15,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B15,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B15,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)

9500
1999
9500-9999






09/01/2024
9804
=IF(MATCH($B16,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B16,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B16,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










09/01/2024
9578
=IF(MATCH($B17,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B17,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B17,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










09/01/2024
9554
=IF(MATCH($B18,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B18,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B18,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










09/01/2024
304
=IF(MATCH($B19,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B19,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B19,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9979
=IF(MATCH($B20,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B20,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B20,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9577
=IF(MATCH($B21,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B21,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B21,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9959
=IF(MATCH($B22,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B22,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B22,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9847
=IF(MATCH($B23,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B23,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B23,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9677
=IF(MATCH($B24,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B24,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B24,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9807
=IF(MATCH($B25,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B25,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B25,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9855
=IF(MATCH($B26,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B26,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B26,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9397
=IF(MATCH($B27,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B27,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B27,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)










10/01/2024
9239
=IF(MATCH($B28,$E$10:$E$15,1)=COUNTA($F$10:$F$15)+1-MATCH($B28,$F$10:$F$15,-1),INDEX($G$10:$G$15,MATCH($B28,$E$10:$E$15,1)),#N/A)











Column A and B are the original data. In range E1:K6 is the COUNTIFS solution. The column C is for the pivot table solution and its formulas refers to the cells in range E9:G15.
Here a screenshot:

